# How to split up the contents of each line of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing. Basically, I have an arraylist called list1. list1 contains:

```
a Mark
c Peter
r Edwin
i Rachel
f Sebastian
p
```

How do I access only the names which come after the singular letter? So for example, I want to access only the names "Mark, Peter, Edwin, Rachel, and Sebastian". I know how to access the first letters "a, c, r, i, f, p" but don't know how to access the rest of the names. Here is what I have so far:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s = it.next();
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
   }
    for (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s1 = it.next();
        for (int i=2; i<s1.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        }

   }
```

This is what my output looks like:

```
a
c
r
i
f
p
MarkPeterEdwinRachelSebastian
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
c
r
i
f
p
Mark
Peter
Edwin
Rachel
Sebastian
```

Comment: `for (String s1 : list1) System.out.println(s1.substring(2));`

Comment: You missed the 'a' in your original output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the issue is with the inner for loop. 
Because you are only using `print` it won't print the line break and everything stays on the same line

```
   for (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s = it.next();
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
   }
   for (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s1 = it.next();
        for (int i=2; i<s1.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to use String's split method and split each string by the blank space.  Then, you would have as a result an array with two elements, the letter and the name.  It should work as follows:

```
    for(String str : list1)
    {
        String[] splitted = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println(splitted[0]);
    }

    for(String str : list1)
    {
        String[] splitted = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println(splitted[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an iterator, you can simply traverse the list using for-each

Short code

```
for (String s : list1) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
}
for (String s : list1) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem if I understand correctly is just a formatting problem instead of this

```
 (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s1 = it.next();
        for (int i=2; i<s1.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        }
```

Try doing

```
 (Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s1 = it.next();
        for (int i=2; i<s1.length(); i++){
            System.out.println(s1.substring(2));
        }
```

Your print is returning everything in a single line rather than another line foreach item in the arraylist.